# Fallout New Vegas Wild Card: Side Bet's (I need help)

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So I got to learn about all the factions that Yes Man had mentioned to me, and I have already ignored the factions I don't like. After I do this I'm very confused as to what I should do. I am a paladin in the brotherhood, but ignored them due to other issues. Mr.House is still alive and running, is that bad if I'm going with the Yes Man track? So how do I continue with the quest? It's very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

For Yes Man, you will have to finish evaluating all the different factions.  He will give you further tasks to complete once the factions are done.